# Sonarqube 7.1 with external MySQL database fails with 'Database must be upgraded` error

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

When setting up Sonarqube v7.1 with external `MySQL` database , I get the following error:

```
2018.06.04 19:11:27 WARN  web[][o.s.s.p.DatabaseServerCompatibility] Database must be upgraded. Please backup database and browse /setup
2018.06.04 19:11:27 WARN  app[][startup] 

      Database must be upgraded.Please backup database and browse /setup

2018.06.04 19:11:27 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Dependency-Check / 1.1.0 / fe3b031e72cf8026980aa916d4a8de32cac1dabc
2018.06.04 19:11:27 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Database needs migration
2018.06.04 19:11:27 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceFilter@7439197 [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/api/system/migrate_db.*, ...], exclusions=[/api/properties*, ...]}]
2018.06.04 19:11:27 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
```

Any pointers how to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an error, you have to open a browser and go to `$SONARQUBE_URL/setup` and validate the form to start the database upgrade.

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing out. Not sure if I was too dumb . But the log message could be more clearer.

Comment: What can be clearer than "Please backup database and browse /setup" ?

Comment: "http://yourSonarQubeServerURL/setup" is clearer, like in their documentation: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/upgrading/